# Proguard Error when trying to export through android studio

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying the export signed APK with Proguard true in android studio.

I get the following error:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':Application:proguardRelease'.
 > java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\AndroidStudioProject\MyFirstProjectonAndroidWear\Application\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar] (Can't read [C:\AndroidStudioProject\MyFirstProjectonAndroidWear\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\20.0.0\classes.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/ParcelableCompat$CompatCreator.class]))
```

I have also given the following in proguard but didn't help:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
```

Here is the proguard file that I am using:

[Proguard File](http://txs.io/MRob)

Comment: i have the same issue! how did you fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Today i got same error, but with picasso library. Check your gradles file and libs folder for duplicate. Like this with me, in gradle file i have
**compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'** (this from maven repository), but also i have  file **picasso-2.3.2.jar**, when i deleted this file, apk file is export without error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to export a release, consider disabling Proguard temporarily:

- 1) edit project.properties , comment out the proguard.config=
- 2)rename the proguard dir under
- 3) rename the proguard*.cfg files